# Customizing the table of contents using TikZ with memoir?

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, memoir

I would like to use a customize table of contents like this one: [How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz) (see the "edit 2") but instead of using the `book` class, I want to use `memoir`. Unfortunately, everything works fine with the `book` class but when I try to create my file with the `memoir` class I have this error:

```
! Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition. \def \reserved@a { \def \@currenvir {tikzpicture}\edef \@currenvli...
```

I tried to locate the part of the code causing this without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit :

the code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=3.8cm,lmargin=3.8cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-1,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[4pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!30}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `titlesec` and `memoir` aren't really compatible, see [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012/)

Comment: Thank you Holene, I modified my post according to your remark.

Thank you for your input @egreg! After reading of the link you posted, shall I abandon the code I posted or is it a way to adapt it to the `memoir` class? Maybe using some native `memoir` possibilities or another package than `titlesec`?

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles:

> all `\sc` to  `\scshape`
>
> the tikzpicture code used inside a `\chapter*` protected against expansion
>
> and the finishing touch with a redefinition of `\chapternumberline`

This being said, you could have a look at package [etoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) for ultimate possibilities of TOC customization, using `TikZ` if you like.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=3.8cm,lmargin=3.8cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-1,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\scshape\bfseries chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!40}\large\scshape\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\scshape\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[4pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\def\chapternumberline ##1{##1 }%
    \chapter*{%
\unexpanded{\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!30}\Huge\scshape\bfseries \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\scshape\bfseries \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Questions of Design}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Drawing}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\chapter{Questions of Technique}
\section{(title section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\section{(title section 2)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 1)}
\subsection{(title sub-section 2)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 

Still, I have an issue about the content label for the chapters (`\thecontentslabel`). It does not appear where it meant to be. The thing is, if I put another label as `\thecontentspage` it will work as intended. The contents label seems to not be "recognized". As a test I tried to add this line:

    \pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=-0.2cm]{ TEST \thecontentslabel};%

beneath this one:

    \pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\scshape\bfseries chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%

But only "TEST" appears. Any clue ?

Comment: @Lorias sorry I am familiar neither with `memoir` nor with `titletoc`...