# Using tikz to create fancy Table of Contents

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, fancyref

I am trying to create a fancy thesis style and I am stuck in the table of contents. I am adopting Pluton's idea from [*How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz) but I get an error stating that

```
! Missing $ inserted. &lt;inserted text&gt; l.1 ...ter}{\numberline
{1}From the Ground Up!}{3}LaTeX Font Warning: Command \large invalid
in math mode on input line 1. LaTeX Font Warning: Command \sc invalid
in math mode on input line 1. ! LaTeX Error: Command \bfseries invalid
in math mode.
```

I don't use any math mode, so I cannot understand where does this come from. My code is the following

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepgflibrary{qrr.shapes.openrectangle}

\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={
  rounded corners=30pt,
  shape=open rectangle,
  open rectangle fill=myblueii,
  open rectangle sides=#1,
  }
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at ([yshift=5pt]titlerect.south west) {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont#1};
  \node[
    mynode=nw,
    anchor=south east,
    fill=myblueii,
    inner xsep=1.5cm,
    outer sep=0pt,
    font=\color{white},
    minimum height=30pt] 
    at (current page.east|-titlerect.north)
     {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[
    anchor=west,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    text width=\paperwidth,
    xshift=-\the\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax,
    outer sep=0pt,
    fill=myblueiii] (titlerect) {};
  \node[
    anchor=south west,
    xshift=2cm,
    text width=\textwidth] 
    at (titlerect.south west) {\Huge#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{60pt}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}

\setlength\beforeepigraphskip{1.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterepigraphskip{2\baselineskip}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{6.8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0.1pt}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\large}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\let\oldepigraph\epigraph \renewcommand\epigraph[2]{%
  \oldepigraph{\color{blue}\itshape #1}{#2}}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand\DoPToC{%
\startcontents\printcontents{}{1}{\noindent{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}}\par\medskip}}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%--------------This is for chapter marks ------------------------

\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}

\backgroundsetup%
{   contents={%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytotalchapters}{\totvalue{chapter} > 0 ? \totvalue{chapter} : 20}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mypaperheight}{\paperheight/28.453}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytop}{-(\thechapter-1)/\mytotalchapters*\mypaperheight}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybottom}{-\thechapter/\mytotalchapters*\mypaperheight}
            \ifcase\thechapter
                \xdef\mycolor{white}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{red}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{orange}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{yellow}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{green}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{blue}
                \or \xdef\mycolor{violet}
                \else \xdef\mycolor{black}
            \fi
            \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
            {\fill[\mycolor] ($(current page.north east)+(0,\mytop)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.5,\mybottom)$);}
            {\fill[\mycolor] ($(current page.north west)+(0,\mytop)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.5,\mybottom)$);}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    },
    scale=1,
    angle=0
}

%-------------------This for fancy ToC---------------------

\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-1,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[4pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!30}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30, rounded corners=15pt] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{From the Ground Up!}
\epigraph{In theory there is no difference \\ between theory and practice. \\ In practice there is.}{Lawrence ``Yogui'' Berra,1925 \\ New York Yankees baseball player}
\DoPToC
\chapter*{A test unnumbered chapter}
\DoPToC
\chapter{Another chapter}
\epigraph{In theory there is no difference \\ between theory and practice. \\ In practice there is.}{Lawrence ``Yogui'' Berra,1925 \\ New York Yankees baseball player}
\DoPToC
\section{A simple section}
\section{Another simple section}

\end{document}
```

I think i is certain that there is a conflict between the *fancy chapter* and the *fancy table of contents* but I don't know how to locate it. Any ideas on what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the last mandatory argument for `\titlecontents` for `chapter` in which you use `\;` which is a math-mode only space and you are trying to use it in text mode; replace those for text-mode spaces.

I marked the problematic line below using "% the problem is here", so you can easily see where the problem is and can apply the necessary correction:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-1,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\scshape\bfseries chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;% the problem is here
 \large\scshape\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
```

Since you are not naturally on math-mode, instead of the incorrect

```
\;\titlerule\;
```

you could use

```
\enspace\titlerule\enspace
```

or

```
\hspace*{6pt}\titlerule\hspace*{6pt}
```

changing `6pt` to whichever length suits your needs.