# Modify Fancy Table of Contents

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I am creating a fancy ToC based on @pluton 's question [How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz)

Although this code works fine, it seems that it missbehaves when using an appendix. Instead of adding an entry `Appendix A` it adds `Chapter A`.

Also when adding an unumbered chapter, i'd rather not to have a `Chapter` as an entry but either a coloured box or nothing at all.

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{tocloft,titletoc,titlesec}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-0.15,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-2.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large \chaptertitlename\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{myblueii}\large\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\hspace*{6pt}\titlerule\hspace*{6pt}\large\bfseries \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.8pc]
{\addvspace{1.0pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small\thecontentspage}
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{myblueii}\Huge \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=15pt] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Second Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Third Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \appendix
 \chapter{First Appendix Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Second Appendix Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter*{Chapter}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

Is there a way to achieve those two requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this is an oversight, or even a bug, in the way that the table of contents is generated.

Inside a latex file the `\appendix` command changes `\@chapapp` from `\chaptername` to `\appendixname` and this is used to get the right title in the chapter and appendix headings. Unfortunately, this information is NOT passed through to the table of contents file (toc). Currently, for example in book.cls, the entry for a chapter or appendix is written to the toc file via:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
```

This means that chapter and appendix entries in the toc file look exactly the same when the `\tableofcontents` is executed, so the toc file cannot differentiate between chapters and appendices (without some hacking). It would be better if there were also

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
```

lines -- although you can not use `\@chapapp` to generate these lines because the value of `\@hapapp` is language dependent...so the code would not be as elegant:(

To get around this problem one solution is to replace the use of `\chaptertitlename` in Pluton's code with, say, `\tocchaptername` and then add the following code to the top of your file:

```
\let\tocchaptername\chaptertitlename
\let\originalAppendix\appendix
\renewcommand\appendix{\originalAppendix%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\appendixname}%
 }
```

With this in place the appendices are labelled as the OP wants. (The use of `\addtocontents` is a hack to write some lines to the toc file without using `\makeatletter\@writefile{toc}...\makeatother`.)

[image]

Actually, the image above requires slightly more than what I have said so far. First, because "appendix" has one more character than "chapter" the spacing requires a small amount of additional tweaking. (To centre chapter and appendix these numbers need to be adjusted more carefully:)

More seriously, the use of `\chapter*` for the last "appendix" results in a blue "appendix" label, which is probably not what you want. It would be a pain to fix this properly (for example, to cope with the case where there are alternating `\chapter{..}` and `\chapter*{...}` commands in the document). Assuming that the OP wants empty labels from this point onwards (as in the image above), then you can just add the line

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\relax}
```

before the `\chapter*{}` command. If some one wanted to alternate the use of starred and unstarred chapters/appendixes then they would need to type

\addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\chaptertitlename}

to let the toc file know what is happening (using the obvious appendix variation in the appendices).

Here is the actual code that I used:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{tocloft,titletoc,titlesec}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\tocchaptername\chaptertitlename
\let\originalAppendix\appendix
\renewcommand\appendix{\originalAppendix\addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\appendixname}}

\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners] (-4,-.1) rectangle (0.10,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-2.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large \tocchaptername\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{myblueii}\large\bfseries\quad}%
{}
{}
{\hspace*{6pt}\titlerule\hspace*{6pt}\large\bfseries \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=0pt] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[2.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[4.8pc]
{\addvspace{1.0pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small\thecontentspage}
[]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{-20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{myblueii}\Huge \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=myblueii,draw=myblueii, rounded corners=15pt] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Second Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Third Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \appendix
 \chapter{First Appendix Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Second Appendix Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\relax}
 \chapter*{Chapter}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Edit - unnumbered chapters**

Finally, to answer your question in the comments, in order to get rid of the empty blue marker for unnumbered chapters replace the `tikzpicture` environment insde the `\titlecontents{chapter}` command above with the following variation (actually, I've improved the code a little at the same time):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
  \ifx\tocchaptername\relax\relax%
  \else%
    \draw(-0.15,0.15)node[anchor=east,align=center,fill=myblueii,text=white,rounded corners,
              rectangle, minimum width=8.5em]{\Large \tocchaptername\ \thecontentslabel};
  \fi%
\end{tikzpicture}\color{myblueii}\large\bfseries}%
```

Using this the output now looks like:

[image]

If there are going to be lots of unnumbered chapters/appendices inbetween numbered ones then you probably want to define a command like the following:

```
\newcommand\unnumberedchapter[1]{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\relax}%
   \chapter*{#1}%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\let\string\tocchaptername\string\chaptertitlename}%
}
```

Then you can just type `\unnumberedchapter{Chapter title}` when you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Although it works for english, when I add `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` I can't get the **chapters** to be named correctly, although appendix name in greek works great! http://imgur.com/b8oJDFX

Comment: @Thanos It should work for arbitrary languages. In fact, I just checked and it is fine with Greek. You need to put the babel specifications *before* the `\let\tocchaptername\chaptername
` line as this is what sets the "chapter" title in the table of contents.

Comment: I put the `babel` specifications right after `documentclass` I got the output I linked to you in the previous comment.

Comment: @Thanos Curious...sorry, my Greek is a little weak and thought that "ἣαπτερ" meant "chapter"...this doesn't mean anything right? It's not obvious to me why it doesn't work especially since the appendices are fine. I'll try and work it out.

Comment: @Thanos OK, this seems to be an issue between babel and one of these packages, not sure which. I have edited my solution to fix the problem: if you use `\let\tocchaptername\chaptertitlename`  then it works with Greek (that is, use `\chaptertitlename` everywhere rather than `\chaptername`). As these two are supposed to be the same at the start of the document this should not make a difference, but it does...

Comment: No need to be soory about your Greek skills! Chapter in greek is spelled *Κεφάλαιο* and is called *Kefaleo*!

Comment: Now it's working! Thank's! I am trying to make a solution with actually a white box instead of a blue one. I changed the last part of the code(before `\begin{document}`) which includes `\chapter*` but it wouldn't do anything at all...Any idea?

Comment: I know about `fill=color` but I want it only to change for the unumbered chapters, so if I change `fill` option in the part `\chapter*{}` nothing actually happens...

Comment: Sorry but which line 13? In your MWE? That's `\contentsmargin` and I don't get anything...

Comment: @Thanos I have added the full details of how to make the blue bullet disappear when there are unnumbered chapters (and I've deleted the comments that I made that sketched how to do this).

Comment: Oops!!! I'm sorry! I forgot to accept it!!! So sorry!!!