# I need this summary

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need this summary 
use tikz library
don't say

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have tried so far? What exactly is the problem with your used code? Please explain your question better!

Comment: You can achieve this with `titletoc` and `tikz`. Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202366/121799 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314359/121799 may serve as starting points. True, they do not look exactly like what you want to achieve, but they can be modified to give you what you want. If you use one of them, start modifying it and get stuck, you will have a code that you can post here and others will up- rather than downvote you, and help you achieve your goal.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to provide one single tcolour box of your own

Then we may analyse your problem in accordance with the following limited permission.**

> © Hachette Livre 2013, 43, quai de Grenelle, 75905 Paris Cedex 15.ISBN
>   : 978-2-01-135590-4
>
> Tous droits de traduction, de reproduction et d’adaptation réservés
>   pour tous pays.Le Code de la propriété intellectuelle n’autorisant,
>   aux termes des articles L122-4 et L122-5, d’une part, que les « copies
>   ou reproductions strictement réservées à l’usage privé du copiste et
>   non destinées à une utilisation collective », et, d’autre part, que «
>   les analyses et les courtes citations » dans un but d’exemple et
>   d’illustration, « toute représentation ou reproduction intégrale ou
>   partielle, faite sans le consentement des auteurs ou de ses ayants
>   droit ou ayants cause, est illicite ».Cette représentation ou
>   reproduction, par quelque procédé que ce soit, sans autorisation de
>   l’éditeur ou du Centre français de l’exploitation du droit de copie
>   (20, rue des Grands-Augustins, 75006 Paris), constituerait donc une
>   contrefaçon sanctionnée par les articles 425 et suivants du Code
>   pénal.

*All rights of translation, reproduction and adaptation reserved for all countries. The Intellectual Property Code authorizing, under the terms of Articles L122-4 and L122-5, on the one hand, only "copies or reproductions strictly reserved for the private use of the copyist and **not intended for collective use**", and, on the other hand, only "**analyses and short** quotations" for the purpose of example and illustration, "any representation or reproduction in whole **or in part, made without the consent of the authors** or their successors or assigns, is illegal". Such representation or reproduction, by any means whatsoever, without authorization from the publisher or the Centre français de l'exploitation du droit de copie (20, rue des Grands-Augustins, 75006 Paris), would therefore constitute an infringement punishable under articles 425 et seq. of the Criminal Code.*