# Customizing toc in book class (appendix and coloring sections depending on current chapter)

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, color, appendices, titletoc

I'm trying to customize my TOC as in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz) (second example) and I'm having two issues.

The first one is documented but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong : I want to write "Appendix" instead of "Chapter". If I don't customize `\titlecontents{chapter}` then everything works fine, but if I do, I get a "Chapter" instead of "Appendix". I've tried all sorts of configs (I think it's due to the book class), with/without `\begin{appendices}`, loading (or not) the appendix package with the titletoc options... Any help would be very appreciated !

The second "problem" I'm having is I'm trying to customize the look of the subsections in the TOC according to the chapter they're in. Each chapter has its own color and I would like the sections to have the same color as the chapter they're in.

Here is my MWE and the result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\definecolor{chapa}{HTML}{15CA7F}
\definecolor{chapb}{HTML}{CA16BD}
\definecolor{chapc}{HTML}{DE1841}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ch@p}{chapa}
\newcommand{\ch@ngeCouleurs}[1]
{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\renewcommand{\ch@p}{chapa}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\renewcommand{\ch@p}{chapb}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\renewcommand{\ch@p}{chapc}}{}
}


\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\contentsmargin{-1.5cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
    {\addvspace{30pt}%
    \ch@ngeCouleurs{\thecontentslabel}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[\ch@p,fill=\ch@p] (-4.2,-.1) rectangle (-.8,.5);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\large\bfseries\sc\@chapapp\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \large\bfseries\color{\ch@p!80!black}}%
    {}
    {}
    {\titlerule\, Page \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \draw[\ch@p] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    [\addvspace{.2cm}]%

\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
    {\addvspace{5pt}}
    {
        \color{\ch@p}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2pc}\color{black}}
    {}
    {\hfill\small\color{black}\thecontentspage}
    [\addvspace{3pt}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{First subsection}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{First appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The result (2.1 and 2.2 should be in purple, and "Chapter A" should be "Appendix A").

[image: Result]

I think I know how to work around the coloring problem of the appendix (comes from the fact that the chapter counter has been reset which can be avoided using packages totcount and assoccnt).

But I don't understand why my `\ch@ngeCouleurs` macro has no effect on the `\titlecontents{section}`. If I could access the chapter number in the `\titlecontents{section}`, that would solve my problem.

Thank you for reading my (long) post ! And thanks to anyone who can provide help !

Comment: I think one issue is that `\ch@p` isn't redefined globally -- `\renewcommand` is not global (unless done in global level)

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `assoccnt` here (I am the author of `assoccnt`, by the way  -- and switch to `xassoccnt` please;-)

Comment: I've been using it to identify whether I'm dealing with an appendix or a chapter and coloring my document accordingly. It's the only way I found to add appendices to my course. See here (no appendix because I've just worked it out this week) : http://alexisfles.ch/files/enseignement/mt11/cours.mta1.etudiant.pdf I want the colored squared to read 1/2/3/4.../A/B/C/...

Comment: Oh, that's nice, and very colourful. How did you achieve the `Proposition` boxes?

Comment: Sorry Christian, I didn't see your comment earlier, but better late than never : you can find the style file for the boxes here : http://alexisfles.ch/en/latex/boites2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\renewcommand{\ch@p}` does not survive the typesetting phase of the chapter title in the ToC and as such, `section` ToC entries use the wrong color setting.

`\renewcommand` is not global (unless being specified directly in the preamble or in the document body outside of nested groups. If the colour settings should be persistent, use `\gdef\ch@p` instead.

Now the `Appendix` issue:

At the time of writing the ToC lines, `\@chapapp` defaults to `Chapter`, so even with an `appendix` environment, this would come too early in the ToC to change to `\appendixname (i.e. 'Appendix'). This can be cured by explicitly writting the redefinition to the`ToC`.

It won't have an effect for later `\@chapapp` usages in the body, since `\tableofcontents` uses `\@starttoc`, which in turn loads the `.toc` file in a group.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

\definecolor{chapa}{HTML}{15CA7F}
\definecolor{chapb}{HTML}{CA16BD}
\definecolor{chapc}{HTML}{DE1841}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ch@p}{chapa}
\newcommand{\ch@ngeCouleurs}[1]
{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\gdef\ch@p{chapa}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\gdef\ch@p{chapb}}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\gdef\ch@p{chapc}}{}
}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \makeatletter
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\@chapapp}{\protect\appendixname}}
  \makeatother
}


\contentsmargin{-1.5cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
    {\addvspace{30pt}%
      \ch@ngeCouleurs{\thecontentslabel}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[\ch@p,fill=\ch@p] (-4.2,-.1) rectangle (-.8,.5);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.7cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\large\bfseries\sc\@chapapp\ \thecontentslabel};%
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      \large\bfseries\color{\ch@p!80!black}}%
    {}
    {}
    {\titlerule\, Page \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \draw[\ch@p] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    [\addvspace{.2cm}]%

\titlecontents{section}[0pc]
    {\addvspace{5pt}}
    {
      \color{\ch@p}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2pc}}%
    {}
    {\hfill\small\color{black}\thecontentspage}
    [\addvspace{3pt}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One chapter}
\section{First section}
\section{First subsection}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{First appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine thanks ! Any idea about the Appendix problem (maybe I shoud have posted two questions)

Comment: @Alexis: See the update, please

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The MWE works, I now need to figure out why it doesn't work in my main document :).

Comment: @Alexis: I see. You can send it to me by mail, and I'll take a look, but probably not this day, yet!)

Comment: Thanks I've worked it out ! One question though : it's now written "Appendix A Appendix First appendix" (which is not the case for chapters). Is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: @Alexis: Remove the `titletoc` option when loading `appendix` (At least, I think this is what you want to achieve: Removing the `Appendix` in the ToC entry line`?)

Comment: For the appendix issue, I finally used this :
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\@writefile{toc}{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\@chapapp{\noexpand\appendixname}}}
}
as I'm using a \input. Plus, the \newcommand didn't work as expected and I had to changed it to \gdef (thanks again for the tip).