# Custom Table of Content for double-sided document using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, double-sided

I am interested in customising a table of content, much like an example posted here in "EDIT 2":

[How to customize the table of contents using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz)

but for double-sided format. I have figured out the different `tikz` settings I need to mirror my output for an odd or even page; my issue lies in wrapping those settings up in a conditional environment to allow the `\tableofcontent` to typeset this automatically. I have experimented with `\scrextend` and `\ifoddpage` but to no avail. Any suggestions?

I am using the `scrreprt` class.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in the form of a minimal working example.

Comment: Given that the code under EDIT 2 does not use a KOMA class and does not load anything which looks likely to provide `\scrextend`, it really isn't clear what you have tried at all. But it isn't a great idea to try combining `titletoc` and a KOMA class. (Mind you, I don't think it's a great idea to combine `titletoc` or `titleXXX` with anything. However, I'm apparently in a minority.)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I was using the classicthesis template and tried making my own modifications - but that was causing all sorts of issues. In the end I put together my own style from scratch and most issues were automatically solved.

Comment: So is this no longer relevant? Could you delete it in that case?