# How to change chapter name for appendices in a customized table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a cutomized table of contents based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/how-to-customize-the-table-of-contents-using-tikz)

But I want to get "Appendix A" instead "Chapter A" in the toc, as happens in this image:
[image]

I provide a MWE of what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Personalización encabezados y pies
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Colores


%============== MÁRGENES =====================%
\usepackage[
  inner =   2cm, % Margen interior
  outer =   2cm, % Margen exterior
  top   =   2cm, % Margen superior
  bottom=   2.5cm, % Margen inferior
  headsep = 30pt,
  footskip = 30 pt,
  includeheadfoot, % Incluye cabecera y pie de página en los márgenes
]{geometry} %Para los márgenes y tipo de página


%=============== PÁRRAFOS ====================%
\usepackage{parskip}
\setparsizes{3em}{20pt}{0pt plus 1fil}



%============= GENERACIÓN DE GRÁFICOS ==========%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, babel}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}


%========= NOMBRE ANEXOS ======================%
\usepackage{appendix} %ANEXOS
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}

    
    
%=== CUSTOMIZE TABLE OF CONTENTS ===%

\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
    { \centering{Tabla de contenidos}} %Cambiar nombre del índice
}


\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\usepackage{kpfonts} 
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}[4.7pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (-4,-.2) rectangle (-0.5,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries capítulo\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}
{\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}
{\color{doc!40}\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Página \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\titlecontents{section}[7.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\dotfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[10pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\dotfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\makeatletter


\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!30}\Huge\sc\bfseries    
\contentsname};%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (11.7,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (11.7,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries 
\contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother



    
    
%========= CAPÍTULOS Y SECCIONES =============%
\usepackage{charter}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{doc!40}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}% entrys in tableofcontents not blue

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection and lower unnumbered

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{doc!40}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
        {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chaptername}}%
        \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
        \vspace{6pt}%
      }}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{doc!40}{%
      \parbox{40pt}{\centering\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}%
    \quad%
  }

\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{doc!40}{%
    \parbox{60pt}{\centering\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}}}%
\quad%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parskip\z@%
    \par\nobreak%
    \Ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{38pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-50pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \parskip\z@%
    \par\nobreak%
    \Ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{42pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introducción}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Justificación}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\chapter{Desarrollo}
 \lipsum[2-5]
\section{Propuesta}
 \lipsum[2-6]
\subsection{Planificación}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\chapter{Conclusiones}
 \lipsum[2-3]

\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
\clearpage
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
\renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
\chapter{Prueba 1}
\chapter{Prueba 2}

\end{document}
```

I've tried by adding `\renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}`, but It only changes the name of the chapter on the respective page and not in TOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use consistently `\chapapp` instead of `\chaptername`, `\appendixname`, or hard-wired words like capitulo. In general, commands structuring the document take care that `\chapapp` expands to whatever is needed.

I suggest the following changes:

- Remove the lines

  ```
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
  ```

  after the line `\usepackage{appendix}`.
- Add the lines

  ```
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
  ```

  after `\addto\captionsspanish{`. Note that it should read `Anexo` in the definition of `\appendixname`, not `Anexos`.
- In the `\titlecontents` command, replace `capitulo` by `\chapapp`.
- In `\renewcommand\chapterformat`, replace `\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chaptername}` by `\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chapapp}`.
- After `\appendix`, replace the lines

  ```
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
  \clearpage
  \addappheadtotoc
  \appendixpage
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Anexo}
  ```

  by

  ```
  \part*{\appendixpagename}
  \addappheadtotoc
  \addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\chapapp\protect\appendixname}
  ```

  Using `\part*` instead of `\appendixpage` has the advantage that the styling of the page fits the other headings.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Personalización encabezados y pies
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames, table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Colores


%============== MÁRGENES =====================%
\usepackage[
  inner =   2cm, % Margen interior
  outer =   2cm, % Margen exterior
  top   =   2cm, % Margen superior
  bottom=   2.5cm, % Margen inferior
  headsep = 30pt,
  footskip = 30 pt,
  includeheadfoot, % Incluye cabecera y pie de página en los márgenes
]{geometry} %Para los márgenes y tipo de página


%=============== PÁRRAFOS ====================%
\usepackage{parskip}
\setparsizes{3em}{20pt}{0pt plus 1fil}



%============= GENERACIÓN DE GRÁFICOS ==========%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, babel}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}


%========= NOMBRE ANEXOS ======================%
\usepackage{appendix} %ANEXOS
   
%=== CUSTOMIZE TABLE OF CONTENTS ===%

\addto\captionsspanish{
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}
     { \centering{Tabla de contenidos}} %Cambiar nombre del índice
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Anexo}
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
}


\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\usepackage{kpfonts} 
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}

\titlecontents{chapter}[4.7pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}}%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (-4,-.2) rectangle (-0.5,.5);%
\pgftext[left,x=-3.5cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries\chapapp\ \thecontentslabel};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}
{\color{doc!40}\large\sc\bfseries}
{\color{doc!40}\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Página \thecontentspage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[fill=doc!25,draw=doc!20] (2pt,0) rectangle (6,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\titlecontents{section}[7.4pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\dotfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[10pc]
{\addvspace{1pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.4pc}}
{}
{\dotfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\makeatletter


\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\chapter*{%
\vspace*{20\p@}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!30}\Huge\sc\bfseries    
\contentsname};%
\draw[fill=doc!30,draw=doc!30] (11.7,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
\clip (11.7,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
\pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries 
\contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother



    
    
%========= CAPÍTULOS Y SECCIONES =============%
\usepackage{charter}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{doc!40}}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{50}{120}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\itshape\rmfamily\small\color{white}}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalcolor}% entrys in tableofcontents not blue

\addtokomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{sectionnumber}{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont\rmfamily\color{white}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsectionnumdepth}% subsubsection and lower unnumbered

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{doc!40}{%
      \parbox[b][60pt]{45pt}{\centering%
        {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chapapp}}%
        \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
        \vspace{6pt}%
      }}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{doc!40}{%
      \parbox{40pt}{\centering\usekomafont{sectionnumber}{\thesection\autodot}}}%
    \quad%
  }

\renewcommand\subsectionformat{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{5pt}%
  \colorbox{doc!40}{%
    \parbox{60pt}{\centering\usekomafont{subsectionnumber}{\thesubsection\autodot}}}%
\quad%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \parskip\z@%
    \par\nobreak%
    \Ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{38pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-50pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
    \parskip\z@%
    \par\nobreak%
    \Ifstr{#3}{}{%
      \rule[\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{1pt}}{%
      \hspace*{42pt}\rule[\dp\strutbox]{\dimexpr\textwidth-70pt}{1pt}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introducción}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Justificación}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\chapter{Desarrollo}
 \lipsum[2-5]
\section{Propuesta}
 \lipsum[2-6]
\subsection{Planificación}
 \lipsum[2-3]
\chapter{Conclusiones}
 \lipsum[2-3]

 \appendix
 \part*{\appendixpagename}
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\chapapp\protect\appendixname}
\chapter{Prueba 1}
\chapter{Prueba 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked perfect!